# How do you convert the field type in CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

The @timestamp field for example, while a long, is always displayed as a date. Can I convert/display it as a long/int?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `toMillis` function:

> Converts the timestamp found in the named field into a number representing the milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html